# Rails 6: How do I create credentials that work in both dev and test but not production without duplication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have created a file to hold development credentials by running

```
EDITOR="subl --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment development
```

So, for example, I can access `Rails.application.credentials.vonage` in dev.

However, doing the same in test, I get `nil`:

```
> Rails.application.credentials.vonage
=> nil
```

How do I set up shared credentials for dev and test but not production without duplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure your test environment to look for the development file and key.

```
# config/environments/test.rb
Rails.application.configure do |config|

  ...

  config.credentials.content_path = Rails.root.join("config/credentials/development.yml.enc")
  config.credentials.key_path = Rails.root.join("config/credentials/development.key")

  ...

end
```

See [Rails General Configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) for more.